# Golang Gorilla Websocket stops receiving information at 120 seconds

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I'm currently trying to connect to the CEX.IO bitcoin exchange's websocket, but have been having issues not only with CEX.IO but with others too. All of my connections drop around the 120-second mark which makes me think there is some TTL problem going on. The Process() goroutine in the main package ends up just hanging and waiting for data from the readLoop which just stops receiving data. I've included some read-only API keys in the code so you can test if you'd like.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "bitbucket.org/tradedefender/cryptocurrency/exchange-connector/cexio"
  "github.com/shopspring/decimal"
  "encoding/json"
  "time"
)

type OrderBook struct {
  Asks []Ask
  Bids []Bid
}

type Ask struct {
  Rate    decimal.Decimal
  Amount  decimal.Decimal
}

type Bid struct {
  Rate    decimal.Decimal
  Amount  decimal.Decimal
}

func main() {
  cexioConn := new(cexio.Connection)

  err := cexioConn.Connect()
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Errorf("error: %s", err.Error())
  }

  err = cexioConn.Authenticate("TLwYkktLf7Im6nqSKt6UO1IrU", "9ImOJcR7Qj3LMIyPCzky0D7WE")
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Errorf("error: %s", err.Error())
  }

  readChannel := make(chan cexio.IntraAppMessage, 25)

  go cexioConn.ReadLoop(readChannel)

  processor := Processor{
    WatchPairs: [][2]string{
      [2]string{
        "BTC", "USD",
      },
    },
    conn: cexioConn,
  }

  go processor.Process(readChannel)

  // LOL
  for {
    continue
  }

}

type Processor struct {
  WatchPairs [][2]string
  conn *cexio.Connection
}

func (p *Processor) Process(ch <-chan cexio.IntraAppMessage) {

  p.conn.SubscribeToOrderBook(p.WatchPairs[0])

  pingTimer := time.Now().Unix()
  for {

    fmt.Printf("(%v)\n", time.Now().Unix())

    if (time.Now().Unix() - pingTimer) >= 10 {
      fmt.Println("sending ping")
      p.conn.SendPing()
      pingTimer = time.Now().Unix()
    }

    readMsg := <- ch
    output, _ := json.Marshal(readMsg.SocketMessage)
    fmt.Println(string(output))

    if readMsg.SocketMessage.Event == "ping" {
      fmt.Println("sending pong")
      p.conn.SendPong()
      pingTimer = time.Now().Unix()
    }

  }
}
```

Below is the connector to the cexio websocket. Here is a link to their API: https://cex.io/websocket-api

```
package cexio

import (
  "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
  //"github.com/shopspring/decimal"
  "github.com/satori/go.uuid"
  "encoding/hex"
  "encoding/json"
  "crypto/hmac"
  "crypto/sha256"
  "bytes"
  "strconv"
  "time"
  "fmt"
)

const Url = "wss://ws.cex.io/ws/"

type Connection struct {
  conn *websocket.Conn
}

type IntraAppMessage struct {
  SocketMessage   GenericMessage
  ProgramMessage  ProgramMessage
}

type GenericMessage struct {
  Event   string      `json:"e"`
  Data    interface{} `json:"data"`
  Auth    AuthData    `json:"auth,omitempty"`
  Ok      string      `json:"ok,omitempty"`
  Oid     string      `json:"oid,omitempty"`
  Time    int64       `json:"time,omitempty"`
}

type ProgramMessage struct {
  Error   string
}

type AuthData struct {
  Key       string  `json:"key"`
  Signature string  `json:"signature"`
  Timestamp int64   `json:"timestamp"`
}

type OrderBookSubscribeData struct {
  Pair      [2]string   `json:"pair"`
  Subscribe bool        `json:"subscribe"`
  Depth     int         `json:"depth"`
}

func (c *Connection) SendPong() error {

  pongMsg := GenericMessage{
    Event: "pong",
  }

  err := c.conn.WriteJSON(pongMsg)
  if err != nil {
    return nil
  }

  deadline := time.Now().Add(15*time.Second)

  err = c.conn.WriteControl(websocket.PongMessage, nil, deadline)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }

  return nil

}

func (c *Connection) SendPing() error {

  pingMsg := GenericMessage{
    Event: "get-balance",
    Oid: uuid.NewV4().String(),
  }

  err := c.conn.WriteJSON(pingMsg)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }

  deadline := time.Now().Add(15*time.Second)

  err = c.conn.WriteControl(websocket.PingMessage, nil, deadline)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }

  return nil

}

func (c *Connection) Connect() error {
  dialer := *websocket.DefaultDialer
  wsConn, _, err := dialer.Dial(Url, nil)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }

  c.conn = wsConn
  //c.conn.SetPingHandler(c.HandlePing)

  for {

    _, msgBytes, err := c.conn.ReadMessage()
    if err != nil {
      c.Disconnect()
      return err
    }

    fmt.Println(string(msgBytes))

    var m GenericMessage
    err = json.Unmarshal(msgBytes, &m)
    if err != nil {
      c.Disconnect()
      return err
    }

    if m.Event != "connected" {
      c.Disconnect()
      return err
    } else {
      break
    }

  }

  return nil
}

func (c *Connection) Disconnect() error {
  return c.conn.Close()
}

func (c *Connection) ReadLoop(ch chan<- IntraAppMessage) {
  for {

    fmt.Println("starting new read")

    _, msgBytes, err := c.conn.ReadMessage()
    if err != nil {
      ch <- IntraAppMessage{
        ProgramMessage: ProgramMessage{
          Error: err.Error(),
        },
      }
      continue
    }

    var m GenericMessage
    err = json.Unmarshal(msgBytes, &m)
    if err != nil {
      ch <- IntraAppMessage{
        ProgramMessage: ProgramMessage{
          Error: err.Error(),
        },
      }
      continue
    }

    ch <- IntraAppMessage{
      SocketMessage: m,
    }

  }
}

func CreateSignature(timestamp int64, key, secret string) string {
  secretBytes := []byte(secret)
  h := hmac.New(sha256.New, secretBytes)

  var buffer bytes.Buffer
  buffer.WriteString(strconv.FormatInt(timestamp, 10))
  buffer.WriteString(key)

  h.Write(buffer.Bytes())

  return hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))
}

func (c *Connection) Authenticate(key, secret string) error {

  timestamp := time.Now().Unix()
  signature := CreateSignature(timestamp, key, secret)

  var authMsg GenericMessage
  authMsg.Event = "auth"
  authMsg.Auth = AuthData{
    Key: key,
    Signature: signature,
    Timestamp: timestamp,
  }

  err := c.conn.WriteJSON(authMsg)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }

  for {
    _, msgBytes, err := c.conn.ReadMessage()
    if err != nil {
      c.Disconnect()
      return err
    }

    fmt.Println(string(msgBytes))

    var m GenericMessage
    err = json.Unmarshal(msgBytes, &m)
    if err != nil {
      c.Disconnect()
      return err
    }

    if m.Event != "auth" && m.Ok != "ok" {
      c.Disconnect()
      return err
    } else {
      break
    }
  }

  return nil

}

func (c *Connection) SubscribeToOrderBook(pair [2]string) error {

  sendMsg := GenericMessage{
    Event: "order-book-subscribe",
    Data: OrderBookSubscribeData{
      Pair: pair,
      Subscribe: true,
      Depth: 0,
    },
    Oid: uuid.NewV4().String(),
  }

  err := c.conn.WriteJSON(sendMsg)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }

  return nil

}

func (c *Connection) GetBalance() error {

  sendMsg := GenericMessage{
    Event: "get-balance",
    Oid: uuid.NewV4().String(),
  }

  err := c.conn.WriteJSON(sendMsg)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }

  return nil

}
```

Comment: There's a lot of code to understand here.  Please describe at a higher level what the program is doing.

Comment: All the program is currently doing is printing out messages it receives from the server. In this case, the program connects to the websocket, authenticates itself using the credentials, and then starts the ReadLoop which simply gathers data and pushes it into the channel.

After the ReadLoop is running I start the Processor.Process goroutine which takes those messages on the channel and prints them at the moment. It also looks for ping messages from the server and responds to them.

Comment: Run the program with the race detector.  It looks like the protocol uses application-level ping/pong. Why do you also send the websocket protocol ping/pong?  The program sends unsolicited websocket protocol pongs to the server. Perhaps the server does not like that. The program can be simplified to eliminate the goroutines.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I added the protocol level pongs because when i was doing application level pongs only I had the same issue, so someone mentioned that it could be an issue with the gorilla package needing protocol pongs?

Comment: For better or worse, ping/pong is the responsibility of the app w/ Gorilla. Gorilla does not send pings on its own or close connection due to lack of messages. You should delete all WriteControl because your app does not take advantage of them nor does it seem that the server does.

Comment: I did as much since they weren't improving my issue at all. I ran it with the race condition checking and it came up clean. The program still stops receiving data at 120 seconds consistently. Any ideas on what it could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to remove the

```
for { 
  continue 
}
```

at the end of the main function

Comment: Hah, I didn't notice that in all of the code.  Use `select {}` to block a goroutine forever.  Better yet, call `processor.Process(readChannel)` directly instead of starting a goroutine. Even better, remove all of the goroutines. They are not required.

Comment: By none of the goroutines being required, I assume you would suggest integrating them all into a single function?

Comment: Remove the loop from `ReadLoop` and return a single IntraAppMessage on every call to the function.  Rename the function to `Read`.  Call `Read` in `Process` instead of receiving a value from the channel.

Comment: Good call, wouldn't have thought of that myself. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @jrgilman if this was the answer, you should mark it as correct when you can so that it it gets filtered out on stack.

Comment: @reticentroot I was only just able to do so, thanks for the reminder though!